# Python typing.get_args and typing.Union

Tags: python-3.8, type-hinting, python-typing, union-types

I'm unable to get any information about the parameter when using `typing.Union`:

```py
import typing

x = typing.Union[str,int]
print(typing.get_args(x))
```

Output: `(<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)`

```py
def f(y: typing.Union[str,int]):
    print(typing.get_args(y))

f(1)
```

Output: `()`

Answer (score 1):

`x` ***is*** a union of types. `y` is of the union type (i.e. either of type `int` or of type `str`).

Try `print(type(x))` and `print(type(y))`.

In your function signature, you merely annotated that `y` should be either of type `str` or of type `int`. So you'll be calling [`get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) on an `int`, when you pass `1` to the function.

`x` in your code is just an alias for that type union object.

In fact, you could do this:

```py
from typing import Union

x = Union[str, int]

def f(y: x):
    ...
```

This is equivalent:

```py
from typing import Union

def f(y: Union[str, int]):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`typing.get_type_hints()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) to get type annotations of `f`:

```py
def f(y: typing.Union[str,int]):
    print(typing.get_type_hints(f))

f(1)
```